# unable to create the handlebar template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, require-handlebars

I am having a handlebar template which takes a JSON object.

Handle Bar Code -

```
<script id="list" type="x-handlebars-template">
{{#each items}} {{! Each item is an "li" }}
<li>
    {{label}} :
    {{value}}
    {{#if items}}
    <ul>
    {{> list}} {{! Recursively render the partial }}
    </ul>
    {{/if}}
</li>
{{/each}}
```

```
<script id="main" type="x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
        {{> list}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

The JSON object as -

```
var items =[
  { "label": "TotalRented", "value": "5" },
  { "label": "AncilleryItems", "items": [
    { "label": "Item", "value": "CarSeat" },
    { "label": "Qty", "value": "2" },
    { "label": "Cost","items": [
          { "label": "VAT", "value": "$20" },
          { "label": "Total", "value": "$100" }
      ]
    },
    { "label": "Item", "value": "GPS" },
    { "label": "Qty", "value": "1" },
    { "label": "Cost", "items": [
          { "label": "VAT", "value": "$10" },
          { "label": "Total", "value": "$50" }
      ]
    }
  ]
  },
  { "label": "Colour", "value": "red" }
 ];

// The main template.
var main = Handlebars.compile( $( "#main" ).html() );

// Register the list partial that "main" uses.
Handlebars.registerPartial( "list", $( "#list" ).html() );

// Render the list.
$( "body" ).html( main( { items: items } ) );
```

This code would render the tree structure data properly for me as in the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/achyut/V6HNd/1/

Now my JSON object has been changed and it now has extra square brackets, for logical seperation. I am not able to render the tree structure with extra brackets now. Can anyone tell what code needs to be changed in the handlebar template.

The new JSON object is

```
var items = [
  { "label": "TotalRented", "value": "5" },
  { "label": "AncilleryItems", "items": [
  [
    { "label": "Item", "value": "CarSeat" },
    { "label": "Qty", "value": "2" },
    { "label": "Cost","items": [
        [
          { "label": "VAT", "value": "$20" },
          { "label": "Total", "value": "$100" }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    { "label": "Item", "value": "GPS" },
    { "label": "Qty", "value": "1" },
    { "label": "Cost", "items": [
        [
          { "label": "VAT", "value": "$10" },
          { "label": "Total", "value": "$50" }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
 ]
},
{ "label": "Colour", "value": "red" }
]
```

Comment: So `items` is now `[ [ { ... }, ... ] ]` instead of `[ { ... }, ... ]`? Why don't you preprocess the data to make it sensible again? Just peel off one layer of arrays in `items`.

Comment: Yes you are right. Regarding peeling off, i actually cant do that because i actually get a very big payload in which items is just one of the objects and i have a very big handlebar template which renders the entire page. This is just a small chunk which i have shared. i cannot write a different logic for this small chunk

Comment: @muistooshort is there no way to rewrite the handlebar code alone to render the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have array of items, you have to loop it again and to access the object you can use `this`

```
{{#each items}} 
   {{#each this}} {{! Each item is an "li" }}

     {{! Code here }}

   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```